# cannot read property 'get' undefined in express when using express router

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my app.js code:

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const ShopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');
const AdminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(ShopRoutes);
app.use(AdminRoutes);

app.listen(3000);
```

both the admin and shop routes interchangeably do not work so I'll post one:

```
const express = require('express');

const Router = express.Router();

Router.get('/add-product', (req,res, next)=>{
    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"></input><button type="submit">Submit</form>');
});
Router.post('/product', (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = Router;
```

It gives the error:

> Router.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{ with get being the problem.

Is there something I'm missing to make router work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"></input><button type="submit">Submit</form>');
});
router.get('/product', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I updated express then restarted the server and it worked will for sure use your shortcut for Router

Comment: Answers with no explanation at all are hard for others to figure out what you changed.  Please add an explanation to add value to your answer for others.